# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 - Is the expiry timespan stored in the token & different sub-domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a verification token I'm using in a system (`system 1`). It is set to a **5 min** timespan in the `identityconfig.cs` on the system that generates it:

```
manager.UserTokenProvider =
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
        dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
    {
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
    };
```

### My question is, does the `TokenLifeSpan` get stored in the token string itself?

The reason I ask is this token is handed off to another system (`system 2`). The same `identityconfig.cs` setting on that system uses a **7 day** lifespan. I want my token to expire after 5 mins at the point of verification on `system 2`.

**Generation Code - System 1:**

`string token_string = await UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("MyPurpose", user_ID);`

**Verification Code - System 2:**

`var result = await UserManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user_ID, "MyPurpose", token_string);`

In addition, it is worth noting:
`System 1` is on `subdomain.mywebsitedomain.com`
`System 2` is on `www.mywebsitedomain.com`

---

Will this allow the token to be passed between for verification? **UPDATE: This will not allow the token to be passed from system 1 to 2..The reason is the 2 sites will sign the token with their own MachineKey. This can be explicitly set in the web.config of each site to allow the tokens to pass between sites.**

---