# How to update Claims in Sub domain if the Authentication token is created by parent Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subdomain, owin, claims-based-identity

I am using MVC with OWIN 3.1.0 and AuthenticationType is ApplicationCookie. I have a Application hosted as sub-domain. For me the Auth cookie is created by Parent domain and my sub domain is using It. The Claims have user_id and few other claims properties.

I wanted to query my Db and get an account Id and keep it in Claims for that user session.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this similar to _part_ of this question about cross domain identity? hope it helps if so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510815/asp-net-identity-2-0-is-the-expiry-timespan-stored-in-the-token-different-su